# Time Complexity (big theta) of for loop nested in while loop

Tags: time-complexity, nested-loops

Function:

```
s <-- 0;  
i <-- n^3;
while (i >= 1) do
    for j <-- 1 to i do 
        constant time operation
    end
i <-- i - sqrt (n);
end;
return (s);
```

I'm having a hard time finding a big omega for this function.  I solved for big O and found that the function was O(n^5.5).  Normally, with arithmetic series, I understand how to solve for big theta when the series is increasing.  My assumption is I am messing up somewhere due to the fact that it is a decreasing series.

Comment: You're testing for i less than or equal to 1, but you've assigned a value of n^3 to i. Did you mean i >= 1?

Comment: @francium yes i did.  sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.